# VelocityUtil is throwing an Exception in try block but cursor is not coming to catch block

Tags: java, exception

I am using the velocity util in my project in order to give the template for the signup email. So my problem is I am creating velocity object by passing the url and hashtable which is in try block.

here I am getting an error as follows 
Timeout while fetching URL: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/****/xxx.vm

So if it exception comes it should come to catch block which is not happening. What might be the possible error here.

```
try{
// my code
VelocityUtil v = new VelocityUtil( new URL( lTemplateUrlString ) , ht );
log.info("after velocity creation");
}
catch(Exception e){
log.info("inside catch");
e.printstacktrace();
}
```

Here when i get the above exception :: Timeout while fetching URL: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/****/xxx.vm  it should come to catch and print inside catch which is not printing. and try block is also not executing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities either:

- The code you posted is not being run at all because the exception is happening elsewhere in the code and not coming from these lines.
- The code that you are running does not include the debugging logger statements that you have added.

To check for both scenarios add a log statement before the `try{`.

Comment: i have a log before try it is printing before going to try. I also added logger statements.

Comment: Replace your VelocityUtil line with a throw new Exception() and see what happens.